# ScrollView goes up in Multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Hiii,

I am Struggling with ScrollView issue for long time.but unable to solve the issue.
Issue is

I Created one Layout in which I have multiple frame Layouts 
Each frame layout is used to contain single fragments.(eg. frame2 is used for fragment 2,frame 3 fro fragment 3 etc.)
frame layouts are oneBelow other.

this is Code :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:id="@+id/svStudentData"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/lnlFrames"
        android:visibility="visible">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/frame2"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame3"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame4"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame5"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame6"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame7"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame8"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame9"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame10"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame11"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame12"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame13"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame14"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame15"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame16"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame17"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame18"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame19"></FrameLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:text="Save"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Data is Already saved "
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/tvNoData"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

fragments are one below other like frag1 then frag2 etc.
Now my question is when my first fragment visibility is gone then the second fragment comes at the top but it goes up.means we cant see the second fragment from the top we have to scroll up to see the top portion of the second fragment.

I tried using things like..

```
scroll_view.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP) ;
```

also

```
scroll_view.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP) ;
```

and

```
scroll_view.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
```

but none worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
 /Just Simply try to use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView/

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:id="@+id/nestedscrollView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:clipToPadding="false"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

     <!-- <include layout="@layout/project_content_main" />-->

     Note: Include you LineaeLayout like above example.

  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

 And don't forget to add android support design Library in Builf.gradle file

 compile 'com.android.support:design:your_version'
```

Comment: @prakshi Can you please attach a screenshot for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try puting this in your scrollView xml tag

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```